# ng-show ng-hide using controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I am trying to edit a field and convert label into text field on click of a button and change it back to label on keypress event (ng-keypress).

I am changing the ng-show variable through controller but it is not working.

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="showCrtl">
       <form>
         <label ng-hide="editMode" >{{field}}</label>
           <input ng-show="editMode" ng-keypress="changemode($event) " ng-model="field" >
           <span class="pull-right" >
           <button ng-click="editMode=true" class="btn-lg btn-warning"  >edit </button>                                       </span>                      
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function showCrtl($scope){
   $scope.field="Chanel";
    $scope.changemode=function(event){
    if(event.charCode==13){
            $scope.editMode = false;
    }
   }
}
```

My updated JS-Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/281/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-blur instead of ng-keypress,

```
  <input ng-show="editMode" ng-blur="changemode() " >
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/uuhzxyjg/)

**EDIT:**

Use the following directive to handle the enter key event,

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/44ywy10x/)

Comment: Then it will chnage to label as soon as I start typing.

Comment: I want to edit the field and then wehn I press enter it should change back to label

Comment: @Rachel Check the updated answer, here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/44ywy10x/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below solution.

```
<input ng-show="editMode" ng-keypress="changemode($event) " >
```

Added interval to update the view

```
function showCrtl($scope, $timeout){

  $scope.changemode=function(event){
   if(event.charCode==13){

   $timeout(function() {
    $scope.editMode = false;
     }, 500);
    }
   }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gsjsfiddle/hcu5mkhm/3/

Comment: It times out and changes to label but the field is not updated.

Comment: After click of enter button the view updated to Channel and edit button. But i didnt get your problem clearly? Which field you are expecting to get updated?

Comment: I updated my fiddle to  make it more clear:  http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/281/

Comment: Updated the fiddle, I hope your issue will get solved now. http://jsfiddle.net/gsjsfiddle/8Yz7S/298/

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working for you is that, you are not preventing the default behavior of `Enter` key. So After `changemode` function is executed and `editmode` is set to `false`, click event of Edit button is also getting executed, setting `editmode` back to `true`.

All you need to do is call `event.preventDefault();` as shown below:

```
function showCrtl($scope){
  $scope.field="Chanel";
  $scope.changemode=function(event){
    if(event.charCode==13){
      $scope.editMode = false;
      event.preventDefault(); // <<<<<<<
    }
  }
}
```

To verify this behavior you can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/8Yz7S/301/

Try it after commenting the line `event.preventDefault();` and check the console.

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

You want to obfuscate as much logic as possible from the view.  So as he suggested, use

```
<input ng-show="editMode" ng-keypress="changemode($event)">
```

Then, do all your logic inside the changemode() function:

```
$scope.changemode = function(evt) {
  $timeout(function() {$scope.editMode = false;},100);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/293/

Comment: You might need to use a timeout to force the digest cycle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/293/